# Is it possible to scroll a div content between another 2 flex divs?

Tags: css

I have a header bar(#A) sticked on top and a footer bar(#C) sticked on the bottom of the page. Each one have a fixed height of `30px` and are represented here by the yellow color. They're sticked on there by the following code: `display:flex; align-content: space-between;`.

Between of these 2 divs there is a red div with the page content(#B), wich is bigger than the screen size. My objective is to let this red div takes only the remaining screen space, keep this height and scroll its content. But when I set `overflow:scroll` the scrollbar shows up with no effect.

I know there is another possibilities to perform this layout like a table with 3 rows, or placing the bars with `position:absolute` / `position:fixed` and get rid of the `display:flex`; but before of jumping out to these alternatives I want to know if the current scenario is possible.

```css
body {
  margin:0px;
}
  
#container {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-align-content: space-between;
    align-content: space-between;
}

#A {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
}
  
#B {
display:inline-block;
width: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
}
  
#C {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id=A style="background-color:gold;"></div>
  <div id=B style="background-color:tomato;">
text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
</div>
<div id=C style="background-color:gold;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
html   { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
body   { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; margin: 0; }

#container { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

#A { flex: 0 0 30px; }

#B { flex: 1 1 auto; overflow: auto; }

#C { flex: 0 0 30px; }
```

http://codepen.io/simoncereska/pen/xZQPXQ

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted? If so, you have a column flow (up and down) so  `flex-direction: column` you should use instead of `row` (that's default).

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: space-between;
}
#A {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
}
#B {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hiden;
  margin: auto;
}
#C {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id=A style="background-color:gold;"></div>
    <div id=B style="background-color:tomato;">
      text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id=C style="background-color:gold;"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you're right, thats what i was looking for! thank you very much.

Comment: I commend you on sticking with flexbox, it is a superior layout. :-)

Comment: Isnt on my question, but I was wondering if there were something such as `calc(100% - 60px);` on CSS without SASS/etc. I didnt know it exists. Now I know and its going to be very useful, thank you again.

Comment: You can definitely use it in many situations involving lengths. You might be interested in this [article](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)