# position absolute has no height

Tags: html, css

I have a fairly simple problem I assume this is common issue however I can't find a solution here on stackoverflow.

I have a 3 div's and the middle on is positioned absolute so the last div floats ontop. How can I make the last div respect the content of the 2nd. I cant use a fixed height because that wouldn't work if the browser was resized.

```css
.box1{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.box2{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px auto;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute; 
}

.box3{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vuyrbbpf/

I would like it so Div3 respects there is content where div2 is in place instead of floating ontop of it

Comment: Why do you need it absolutely positioned?

Comment: i'm using top:100%; so div2 isn't show above the first browser fold

Comment: Can you give a sketch/rough drawing of the desired result?

Comment: @CourtneyBall I don't see anywhere you are using  `top:100%` and it's very unclear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Still pretty unclear on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It sounds like you want "dialog" behavior... with a fixed height header and footer div, and a middle "body" div that stretches to fill the remaining height of your screen space left between the header and footer... is that correct?

Comment: Sketch as requested here - http://puu.sh/n30LN/ce41f3a830.png

Comment: I think he want "one page scroll" website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As @leandro pointed out, the space between the footer and bottom of the content was a blank. Fixed it by assigning the footer with `position: fixed`

---

**UPDATE**

In light of new information, I have made a flexbox based layout that looks to be in the same nature as [this image](http://puu.sh/n30LN/ce41f3a830.png). I took the liberty of changing the bottom box, `box3` as a footer and the middle `box2` as a content box that scrolls vertically whilst the header `box1` and the footer `box3` are `position:fixed` and `absolute` respectively.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: space-around;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.box3 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div clas="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">BOX1 HEADER</div>
  <div class="box2">
    <h1>START of CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>END of CONTENT</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">BOX3 FOOTER?</div>
</div>
```

- Use flexbox on the `.wrapper` `display: flex`...
- ...in a direction of vertical is `flex-direction: column`...
- ...arranging the flex-items (20x20px boxes) with evenly spaced areas between them `align-items: space-between`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: space-between;
  }

.box1{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.box2{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px auto; 
}
.box3{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see an image representing some layout..and what are you trying to convey to me, sir?

Comment: This image from topic starter) He want something like that) See comments under question.

Comment: Should be easy, one moment, please.

Comment: Yes, its easy if I understand question well) https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/j0dv9753/

Comment: zer00ne, you made a flex layout to answer my question [-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285149/is-it-possible-to-scroll-a-div-content-between-another-2-flex-divs) that works good on fullscreen. But, at least on my screen, this one here have a white hole when I click 'full page'. [-check it out](https://i.gyazo.com/778e10dd8a35a18214ed94ea134ff8fc.png)

Comment: @Leandro fixed. Thank you, sir.