# Howto scroll a context flex div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple site layout of Header and a 3 columns main section. The middle column should contain a lengthy content so I would like it to scroll, I can't make it happen.
Here is a prototype of the problem:
http://codepen.io/ValYouW/pen/GZxKBa

**UPDATE:** Sorry for not mentioning, but I meant for horizontal-scroll, not vertical...

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#layout {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

#header {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

#main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#facets{
  border: 2px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

#report {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#rightside {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

#chips {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

#leads-grid {
  border: 4px solid orange;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#grid1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="facets">Facets</div>
    <div id="report">
      <div id="chips">Chips</div>
      <div id="leads-grid">
        <div id="grid1">How to make my parent (#leads-grid) scroll?</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightside">Right side</div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Any ideas how to make #leads-grid to scroll?
Thx.

Comment: `#leads-grid` does scroll already: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONvJEp

Comment: Do you mean make `#grid1` scroll? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqzOKZ

Comment: For Firefox you would need to add `min-height: 0` to `#main` and `#leads-grid`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNYWBa

Comment: [check this question it may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285149/is-it-possible-to-scroll-a-div-content-between-another-2-flex-divs)

Comment: @Michael_B Sorry for not mentioning, but I meant for horizontal-scroll, not vertical...

Answer (score 0):

for the leads-grid have scroll his son (grid1) needs to surpass the content. try to put a lot of br's into the content of grid1 and leads-grid will create a scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Your **#leads-grid** is scrolling already.
You just need to add more content to **#leads-grid**.

See code below. I have added **height: 5000px** to **#grid1** as inline style. Scroll appears.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#layout {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

#header {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

#main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#facets {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

#report {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#rightside {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

#chips {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

#leads-grid {
  border: 4px solid orange;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#grid1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="facets">Facets</div>
    <div id="report">
      <div id="chips">Chips</div>
      <div id="leads-grid">
        <div id="grid1" style="height: 5000px;">How to make my parent (#leads-grid) scroll?</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightside">Right side</div>
  </div>
  <div>
```